# rate of decay of tail sum of convergent series implies rate of decay of individual series terms?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum_{j=J}^\infty\theta_j^2 \leq AJ^{-2k+1}$ for some constant $k>1$ and all $J\geq 1$, does this tell us something about how fast $\theta_j^2$ decays?

PS: One can show if $\theta_j^2\leq j^{-2k}$, then $\sum_{j=J}^\infty\theta_j^2 \leq \tilde{A}J^{-2k+1}$ for some constant $\tilde{A}$. Wondering if above will imply the converse of this statement.

Comment: $$\theta_J^2\leq \sum_{j=J}^\infty\theta_j^2 \leq AJ^{-2k+1}$$

Comment: @GabrielRomon lol wondering if we can get some faster rate than that...

Comment: @GabrielRomon 's bound can be attained.

Comment: @lcv I guess what I meant was if we can get some tighter bound than Gabriel suggested.

Comment: You need to know more about the $\theta_j$. Otherwise you can cook up examples that behave like Gabriel's bound. But if you have equality instead of inequality you can "differentiate" over $J$ and get your estimate.